# Tips for creating a pumpkin texture

Tags: modeling, node-editor, shader-nodes

I used the video tutorial by Ryan King to make a pumpkin model and just learned some pretty cool ways to make the pumpkin texture by using nodes, but I don't know many of the nodes and what they can do, so I'm just wondering what nodes I could use to make this type of pumpkin below.

[image]

Comment: pretty much the same set of nodes, but with different colors and settings.  Experiment with the material and see what happens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recommend putting on a couple layers of distortion to get the colors broken up with spots of different sizes.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Maybe to start, try somethings like this. A Wave Texture provides the vertical lines, and a Noise Texture provides the "speckles". Make sure to use UV texture coordinates, otherwise the lines will only cross one axis and won't "wrap around" the sphere nicely.

I used the Noise Texture as a basis for a small Vector Warp of the input Vector to the Wave Texture which makes the lines more fuzzy/random. This plus a small amount of distortion on the Wave Texture itself makes the vertical lines more realistic (less linear and fake looking).

I used the Wave Texture as a basis for a bit of a Bump, but not the Noise. This is just a personal choice, and you can use them both if you wish, just make sure the speckles are "softer" than the waves when mixed.

Speaking of softening, you can see in several instances, I mixed the value going into an input socket (quite heavily) with white first. This is because procedurally generated values are often too "strong" (gives weird effects), and lowering the contrast first often makes things better. I use the MixRGB with white because the slider gives good, precise control.

This isn't the end result, but is should go a good way towards getting you started. Let me know if you have any questions ;)

[image: Pumpkin]

Comment: What is that purple node that is called add. I can't find that when I search it. Is it a separate node I have to install to get?

Comment: It is *Vector Math* @AlexWillis21